# MySQL Join issues

Tags: mysql, left-join

**Edit 2:

Nothing to find here, its my fail in other place.

Who knew `!= NULL` doesn't work in MySQL.

Moderator delete this please?**

I got a `eav` database that I need to select some products with attributes from it.
When I use

```
select attribute1.value as a1, attribute2.value as a2, products.id
from attributes attribute1, attributes attribute2, products
where product.id = attribute1.product_id and attribute1.name = 'abc' and
    product.id = attribute2.product_id and attribute2.name = 'def'
```

I don't get all products when an attribute is missing on one products and I need to get all products with `NULL` if there are missing attributes.
When I use

```
select attribute1.value as a1, attribute2.value as a2, products.id
from products
left join attributes as attribute1 on (product.id = attribute1.product_id and attribute1.name = 'abc')
left join attributes as attribute2 on (product.id = attribute2.product_id and attribute2.name = 'def')
```

I get all products, but all products have `a1 = NULL` even when in the database they dont.
What is the problem?

Example:

products:

```
 id
1000
1001
1002
1003
```

attributes:

```
name    product_id    value
abc        1000         1
abc        1002         2
def        1000         3
def        1001         4
```

Expected result:

```
 id     a1      a2
1000    1       3
1001   NULL     4
1002    2      NULL
1003   NULL    NULL
```

Result from first query:

```
 id     a1      a2
1000    1       3
```

Result from second query:

```
 id     a1      a2
1000   NULL     3
1001   NULL     4
1002   NULL    NULL
1003   NULL    NULL
```

EDIT:

Fixed the second query and example.

Comment: Could you please post some sample database entries and what you would expect from the query? Also your second query seems to be missing the FROM clause.

Comment: Apart from some more typos (product **s** .id) the edited query is correct. It should give the right result.

Comment: Is there anything different to your 'real' query / database structure (except for names)? Did you try to reconstruct it with a minimal example (such as the one you outlined in the post).

Comment: yes, its a bloated database, and I reconstructed it with minimal example

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues:

1. You're missing a `from` clause to start the query
2. You need to use the correct table aliases for the `attribute.name` tests, specifically `attribute1.name` and `attribute2.name`.

Try it this way:

```
select attribute1.value as a1, attribute2.value as a2, products.id
    from products
        left join attributes as attribute1 
            on products.id = attribute1.product_id 
                and attribute1.name = 'abc'
        left join attributes as attribute2 
            on products.id = attribute2.product_id 
                and attribute2.name = 'def'
```

Comment: @Dani: This is pretty straight-forward and should work as expected. What results are you getting from this query? Are there any other details you're omitting from the question?

Answer (score 0):

Query

```
select attribute1.value as a1, attribute2.value as a2, products.id
left join attributes as attribute1 on (product.id = attribute1.product_id and attribute.name = 'abc')
left join attributes as attribute2 on (product.id = attribute2.product_id and attribute.name = 'def')
```

Is not right, where table with products?

**And also what is the attribute.name, your have no table with name/alias attribute**

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work you have to replace first JOIN with FROM, like this:

```
SELECT attribute1.value AS a1, attribute2.value AS a2, products.id
FROM attributes AS attribute1 ON (product.id = attribute1.product_id AND attribute.name = 'abc')
LEFT JOIN attributes AS attribute2 ON (product.id = attribute2.product_id AND attribute.name = 'def')
```

Comment: I guess you provided wrong SQL, where "FROM products" was missing. Other wise your query is valid. NULL value is very common for LEFT JOINs where value could not be found, you can use more strict joins like INNER or RIGHT in order to get exact results.